# Changing the imshow origin

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow, yaxis

I have a table of data with 3 columns, which I want to plot the third column in terms of the first two in a colorful 2D plot. For example for the following table i.e.

```
4.0 4.0 0.313660827978 
4.0 5.0 0.365348418405 
4.0 6.0 0.423733120134 
5.0 4.0 0.365348418405 
5.0 5.0 0.439599930621 
5.0 6.0 0.525083754405 
6.0 4.0 0.423733120134 
6.0 5.0 0.525083754405 
6.0 6.0 0.651536351379
```

I use the following code:

```
x,y,z = np.loadtxt('output_overlap.dat').T #Transposed for easier unpacking
nrows, ncols = final_step_j-1, final_step_k-1
grid = z.reshape((nrows, ncols))
plt.imshow(grid, extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.max(), y.min()),
           interpolation='nearest', 
           cmap='binary')
fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('m1')
plt.ylabel('m2')
plt.draw()
fig1.savefig('test.pdf', dpi=100)
close('all')
```

which gives me the following plot:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31460244/test.png

Which is correct. Now, my question is: how can I change the order of showing data in the Y axis? I would like to have the point (4,4) at the origin.

I have tried changing

```
plt.imshow(grid, extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.max(), y.min())
```

to:

```
plt.imshow(grid, extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max())
```

It does change the numbers in the grid but not the actual data. This is not the solution. Anybody can give me a help here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The extent just assigns those corner coordinates to the data, it doesn't change the order of the underlying data in anyway.

`imshow` has a `origin` keyword for this, see:

```
a = np.array([0.313660827978, 0.365348418405, 0.423733120134, 
              0.365348418405, 0.439599930621, 0.525083754405, 
              0.423733120134, 0.525083754405, 0.651536351379]).reshape(3,3)

extent = [4,6,4,6]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)

axs[0].imshow(a, extent=extent, interpolation='none')
axs[1].imshow(a, origin='lower', extent=extent, interpolation='none')
```

[image]

You can also consider `np.flipud` and `np.fliplr` to mirror an axis of the array. But i personally prefer setting the origin with imshow if that's sufficient.