# Python: Plot Data with 0s 1s H-bond Data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a molecular dynamics simulation data. The system has 254 solute molecules and almost 12000 water molecules. The simulation has almost 4700 frames. I have extracted the H-bond data. The data is like if any of solute molecules show H-bond with any of the water molecule, it displays 1 otherwise 0. I want to plot H-bond data. So in total there is 254*4700 data points. The data is like as in given example

```
S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 ...
0  0  0  0  0  ...
0  0  0  0  0  ...
0  1  1  0  0  ...
0  0  0  0  0  ...
0  0  1  1  1  ...
0  0  0  0  1  ...
0  1  0  0  1  ...
0  0  0  0  1  ...
...
```

I want to plot like if the datapoint is 1, it shows a color otherwise if 0, no color (just like any other plot, e.g. scatter plot). Furthermore I want two axes on the plot such that
x-axis=Number of solutes (1 ... 254)
y-axis=number of frames (1 ... 4700)

So on y-axis only that datapoint related to x-axis should be colored that have 1.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is the format of your input? A pandas dataframe? A text file? A numpy array? I also don't understand what the [desired output](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html) format is. A scatter plot? A heatmap?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [plt.imshow](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) for this task:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

solutes = 254
frames = 4700
data = np.round(np.random.rand(frames, solutes))
plt.imshow(data, aspect='auto', interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, yes it worked, but there is one issue as also shown in your plot, "the y-axis values are inverted, it should be like 0 of x-axis and 0 of y-axis should meet at origin". Can you tell if this is possible? I have solved this by sorting data before loading. Thanks

Comment: @MirzaAhmedHammad Absolutely, just add origin='lower' to the argument list. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728445/changing-the-origin-of-a-plot